# Combine duplicate elements and sum the amount

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array object with incomes, for any duplicate incomes I want to have a single record which has a sum of all duplicates.

```
This the array object

const incomes = [
  {
    incomeType: 'DIVIDEND',
    incomeSubType: 'RECEIPT',
    payerName: 'Employer',
    expiryDate: '2022-03-10',
    regularAmountCalculated: {
      value: 2500,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    },
    irregularAmountCalculated: null,
    bonusCalculated: {
      value: 200,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    }
  },
  {
    incomeType: 'DIVIDEND',
    incomeSubType: 'RECEIPT',
    payerName: 'Employer',
    expiryDate: '2022-03-10',
    regularAmountCalculated: {
      value: 2500,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    },
    irregularAmountCalculated: null,
    bonusCalculated: {
      value: 200,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    }
  }
];
```

I am expecting the output to have a only on record for Dividend and calculated amount as 5000.

```
Expected output

const incomes = [
  {
    incomeType: 'DIVIDEND',
    incomeSubType: 'RECEIPT',
    payerName: 'Employer 1',
    expiryDate: '2022-03-10',
    regularAmountCalculated: {
      value: 5000,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    },
    irregularAmountCalculated: null,
    bonusCalculated: {
      value: 200,
      currencyCode: 'AUD'
    }
  },
];
```

I have written:

```
const totals:any = [];
statementOfIncomes.forEach(x => {
  const obj = totals.find(o => o.incomeType === 'DIVIDEND');
  if (obj) {
    obj.regularAmountCalculated.value = obj.regularAmountCalculated.value + x.regularAmountCalculated?.value;
  } else {
    totals.push(x);
  }
});
```

The error I get is

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object '[object Object]'**

Comment: I have tried same code and it's working fine as per you expected output

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store all unique incomes.
You have to loop over your incomes, check if the map already has an entry based on the `incomeType`. If not, add it to the map, else get the existing value and add the `regularAmount` to it.
Last you have to convert your map back to an `Array`.
This has a runtime of `O(2n)` instead of `O(n^2)` as stated in your first approach.

```js
const map = new Map();

incomes.forEach((income) => {
  if (!map.has(income.incomeType)) {
    map.set(income.incomeType, income);
  } else {
    const existingIncome = map.get(income.incomeType);

    existingIncome.regularAmountCalculated.value += income.regularAmountCalculated.value;

    map.set(income.incomeType, existingIncome);
  }
});

const uniqueIncomes = Array.from(map, ([_key, value]) => value);

// [
//   {
//     incomeType: 'DIVIDEND',
//     incomeSubType: 'RECEIPT',
//     payerName: 'Employer',
//     expiryDate: '2022-03-10',
//     regularAmountCalculated: { value: 5000, currencyCode: 'AUD' },
//     irregularAmountCalculated: null,
//     bonusCalculated: { value: 200, currencyCode: 'AUD' },
//   },
// ];
```